# Lazy loading image from s3 bucket in React 18 (still slow)

Tags: reactjs, image, amazon-s3, lazy-evaluation, bucket

I'm trying to lazy load image in React 18, but even using the `loading` prop with `lazy` value, even wrapping with `Suspense` component, loading is still slow.

I've checked the profiler, nothing unusual I can find...
How I can debug slow rendering of the lazy loaded image.

BR